# $L^{un} = L\cdot k^{un}$ without separability hypothesis

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, local-field

I'm reading the book *Fesenko & Vostokov "Local fields and their extensions"* and I can't prove a simple statement.

The setting is the following: we have a complete discrete valuation field $(F,v)$ (actually, in the book they assume $F$ only to be Henselian but I don't need this level of generality). Let $L$ be an algebraic extension of $k$ such that $L$ with the valuation $w$ that extends $v$ is a complete discrete valuation field. For my purposes, we can suppose $L \supset k$ to be a finite extension. Also, in the text it's supposed that $L^{alg}=F^{alg}.$ We denote the residue fields by $\bar{k},\bar{L}.$ In general, the extension $\bar{L} \supset \bar{k}$ is not separable. If it's separable I have no problems and everything works.

The proposition states that $L^{un} = L\cdot k^{un}$ where $L^{un},k^{un}$ stands for the maximal unramified extension of $L,k$ in an algebraic closure. In the proof, I can't verify the following sentence:

> The compositum of the fields $\bar{k}^{sep},\bar{L}$ coincides with $\bar{L}^{sep}$ since $\bar{L}\supset\bar{k}$ is an algebraic extension.

Abstractly, consider and algebraic extension $K \supset k$ and their separables closures $K^{sep},k^{sep}.$

**Why is $K^{sep}=K\cdot k^{sep}$?**

The inclusion $K\cdot k^{sep} \supset K^{sep}$ is trivial and the problem is the other inclusion. My attempt was to consider the expression $k^{sep} = k(X)$ with $X$ the set of all roots of separable polynomials over $k.$ This way, we have that $K\cdot k^{sep} = K(X)$ but I can't prove that this field coincide with $K^{sep} = K(Y),$ with $Y$ the set of all  roots of separable polynomials over $K.$

I've given the context since it could be helpful although I think my problem is only about fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a finite extension $K/k$ (you can extend to any algebraic extension),

$K^{sep}=K(k^{sep})$ follows from that when $a$ is separable over $k$ then $k(a^{p^n})=k(a)$.

(proof: $k(a)/k(a^{p^n})$ is purely inseparable, if it wasn't trivial then $k(a)/k(a^{p^n})/k$ wouldn't be separable)

Thus, $$K^{sep}=K((K^{sep})^{p^n})$$

With $p^n$ the largest power of the characteristic dividing $[K:k]$ then every element of $K^{p^n}$ is separable over $k$ so that $$(K^{sep})^{p^n}= (K^{p^n})^{sep}\subset k^{sep}$$
and hence $$K^{sep}=K((K^{sep})^{p^n})\subset K(k^{sep})$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I only have one question. How do you prove that $(K^{p^n})^{sep} \subset (K^{sep})^{p^n}$? For your proof we only need the other inclusion and I'm able to prove it, but I'm curious about the equality since it's the first time I'm working without separability hypothesis and I would like to see proofs in this context.

Comment: Simply apply the $p^n$ homomorphism to $a\in K^{sep}$ and the coefficients of its minimal polynomial, every separable minimal polynomial $\in K^{p^n}[x]$ is obtained this way @DrinkingDonuts